# Continuous vs classical structures (2)

Tags: model-theory, nonclassical-logic

I am moving my first steps in [continuous model theory](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~begnac/articles/mtfms.pdf) ([tl;dr](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~jcchubb/Slides/ContinuousModelTheoryWeb.pdf)). This is one of two *soft questions* on the relation between a continuous and a classical structure.

Let $M$ be a classical first-order structure of signature $L$. For simplicity assume $M$ saturated an $L$ countable. Let $d$ be a pseudometric that induces the topology generated by the $0$-definable subsets of $M$. (It exists by Urysohn metrization theorem.)

Let $M^c$ be the continuous (pre)structure with the same support as $M$, the same functions as $M$, the pseudometric $d$ introduced above, and the canonical $\{0,1\}$-valued functions for the relations of $L$.

How is this related to the original first order theory? (I apologize for the open-endedness.)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't $M^c$ simply compact under those assumptions?

Comment: This is a good point, indeed.

Comment: In that case, the relationship (if any) is really superficial. This $M^c$ is just the space of $1$-types over the empty set (up to a Kolmogorov quotient, anyway). Compact structures in continuous logic correspond with the finite structures in discrete FOL, they are completely categorical.

Comment: @tomasz That should be an answer I think.